# How do I check which database my heroku app is using?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When listing the addons to my applications in Heroku, I see two postgresql databases for the same app:

```
heroku-postgresql:hobby-basic  boston-xxxx-7435          myapp            $9.00/month
heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev    xxxx-messy-4538           myapp            free
```

I got a notice saying that the dev database exceeded 10,000 rows, but I thought I upgraded to the basic level already.

How can I check to see which one I'm actually using? And if I'm already using the basic one as I suspect, do I have to drop the dev database?

Comment: Did you promote the hobby-basic database to the primary database after creating it (and copying data from the previous one) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
heroku pg:info --app YourAppName
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
heroku pg:info --app YourAppName
```

as Akshay mentioned in his answer to see the status of your databases on heroku.

If you got a notice saying that your database has exceeded 10,000 rows, that means you are no longer eligible for the free tier and you need to upgrade your database plan on heroku.

I have gone through the exact same situation as yours couple of years ago and I found [this awesome gist](https://gist.github.com/rtwomey/3165360) which nicely explains how to upgrade your database plan on heroku safely i.e. taking proper data backup and at last deleting the old database.